# Overriding Laravel 5 delimiters

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using AngularJS with Laravel in my application. The problem that is face is both of them use the same delimiter.

I want to override Laravel's delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines to `AppServiceProvider@register`:

```
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('[[', ']]'); 
Blade::setContentTags('[!!', '!!]');.
```

After this your will be able to use variables in templates like this:

```
[[ $phpVar ]]    // PHP
{{ angularVar }} // AngularJS
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to limonte's answer, you can add `@` at the beginning of any angular statement that uses the handlebars so blade won't touch it, this can be a good work around if you don't want to completely replace the handlebars.

Example:

```
@{{ $scope.var }} // won't be read by blade!
```

See docs for more info: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates